# Why can't c# get the correct parameter value from unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, c, winapi

Win32 program as below:

```
 #ifdef A_EXPORTS
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
 #else
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
 #endif
extern "C" DLL_API  void EC_GetGin(int* icard);
void EC_GetGin(int* icard)
{
    icard = 1;
}
```

C#  code as below:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", EntryPoint = "EC_GetGin", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void EC_GetGin(ref int icard);

int icard = 0;
EC_GetGin(ref icard);
```

Why can't C# get 1 ？

Answer (score 4):

Your C code modifies the pointer rather than writing to the variable it points to. Change it to

```
void EC_GetGin(int* icard)
{
    *icard = 1;
}
```

The C# code would be cleaner if you declared the argument as `out` rather the `ref`.

Answer (score 1):

In your C code you don't set the value in the memory location, but change the pointer in `icard` (you let `icard` point to memory location `1`).

To change the value in the memory location `icard` points to use

```
*icard = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the value, use `*` with the pointer to get the value.

```
void EC_GetGin(int* icard)
{
    *icard = 1;
}
```